# how to position a button div in a dynamically changeable div?

Tags: html, css

Hi I created a slider in which I want to give a button to the slider Which should look like this[image: Before Slider Div **Width** Changes]

I created The Button To the slider with the following code.all looks good

```
#sliderdiv 
{
    top:30%;     
    right: -2px; 
    position:fixed;
    width:300px;
    height:270px;
    margin-right: -300px;
}
#buttondiv
{                  
    height:110px;
    width:40px;
    background:aqua;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    margin-left: -39px;                                     
}

<div id="sliderdiv">
    <div id="buttondiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when the width of the slider changes the button moves from it like this[image: when slider width changed]

I Know This is because of the **margin-left** value which i give to the button div.Here is the question i have is there a way to position it correctly even when the slider div is automatically changed?

Or Is there a way to place the button to slider div without any gap and without changing the button div values?

Thanks...

Here is the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sNgxR/3/

Comment: ok, fast one. I don't really understand your issue, but check out this jsfiddle I made with you code and try to give it back with your problem and I will have a look.
http://jsfiddle.net/sNgxR/

Comment: Are you using some javascript code to change (or maybe slide) that div?

Comment: can u please create a sample on jsfiddle? I tried to create using ur css but it is not working properly (may be due to the size u used in ur css).

Comment: i tried to reproduce the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/sNgxR/

Comment: wait i'll give you jsfiddle

Comment: @jaay Yes I'm using js.

Comment: @bboy I have Given js Fiddle According to your Style Check my edits:)

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: I don't see a problem in Chrome beta?

Comment: @bboy When i change div size then the button look like 2nd image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out:

```
var mywidth = $("#buttondiv").width();
$("#buttondiv").css("margin-left", -mywidth);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sNgxR/4/

edit the Width of your button and hit run.

if you change the val of the slider, it works fine